# Is there any way to gift a Geforce Now priority membership to someone account?

Tags: geforce-now

One of my friend is playing with US through Geforce Now. For his birthday we would like to gift him one year of Geforce Now:

[image: screenshot of pay tier]

I dont know if it is actually possible. Since it is a gift, we would like to avoid to just give him $100 directly (but we may end to). After looking a bit online, I found that it may be possible through google play gift card. I cant find a direct source though:

- [reddit: GeForce Now Gift Cards: Where can I buy them?](https://www.reddit.com/r/GeForceNOW/comments/k951iy/geforce_now_gift_cards/)
- [nvidia forum: google play gift card](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/discover/166761/google-play-gift-card/)
- [GeForce NOW Nvidia Code](https://gameflip.com/en/item/geforce-now-nvidia-code-read-description-/1f629a06-fb6a-4ab6-8aef-a38a8052808e) (<-- this one looks shady)

It must be an official way to buy one because I found a [redeem page](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/account/redeem/):

[image: redeem screenshot]

So is there any official way to gift a Geforce Now priority membership to their account?